# Retrieving last row inserted in table for each "parameter"

Tags: mysql, select

I have a table, currently about 1.3M rows which stores measured data points for a couple of different parameters. It is a bout 30 parameters.

Table:

```
* id
* station_id (int)
* comp_id (int)
* unit_id (int)
* p_id (int)
* timestamp
* value
```

I have a UNIQUE index on: `(station_id, comp_id, unit_id, p_id, timestamp)`

Due to timestamp differ for every parameter i have difficulties sorting by the timestamp (I have to use a group by).

So today I select the last value for each parameter by this query:

```
select p_id, timestamp, value
from (select p_id, timestamp, value
      from table
      where station_id = 3 and comp_id = 9112 and unit_id =  1 and
            p_id in (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)
      order by timestamp desc
     ) table_x
group by p_id;
```

This query takes about 3 seconds to execute.
Even though i have index as mentioned before the optimizer uses filesort to find the values.

Querying for only 1 specific parameter:

```
select p_id, timestamp, value from table where station_id = 3 and comp_id = 9112 and unit_id =  1 and p_id =1 order by timestamp desc limit 1;
```

Takes no time (0.00).

I've also tried joining the parameter-ids to a table which I store the parameter ID's in without luck.

So, is there a simple ( & fast) way to ask for the latest values for a couple of rows with different parameters? 
Doing a procedure running a loop asking for each parameter individually seems much faster than asking all for once which I think not is the way to use a database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query is incorrect.  You are aggregating by `p_id`, but including other columns.  These come from indeterminate rows, and the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/group-by-handling.html) is quite clear:

> MySQL extends the use of GROUP BY so that the select list can refer to
>   nonaggregated columns not named in the GROUP BY clause. This means
>   that the preceding query is legal in MySQL. You can use this feature
>   to get better performance by avoiding unnecessary column sorting and
>   grouping. However, this is useful primarily when all values in each
>   nonaggregated column not named in the GROUP BY are the same for each
>   group. The server is free to choose any value from each group, so
>   unless they are the same, the values chosen are indeterminate.
>   Furthermore, the selection of values from each group cannot be
>   influenced by adding an ORDER BY clause.

The following should work:

```
select p_id, timestamp, value
from table t join
     (select p_id, max(timestamp) as maxts
      from table
      where station_id = 3 and comp_id = 9112 and unit_id =  1 and
            p_id in (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)
      order by timestamp desc
     ) tt
     on tt.pid = t.pid and tt.timestamp = t.maxts;
```

The best index for this query is a composite index on `table(station_id, comp_id, unit_id, p_id, timestamp)`.

Comment: Thank you, I will test the query tonight. A question. Is there any difference in performance using INDEX vs UNIQUE?

Comment: Both create an index, so they should be equivalent.

Comment: This worked pretty neat. Thank you very much! Execution time went from almost 3 seconds down to 0.4 seconds.